# Does SMS permission require to send an SMS to user?

Tags: android

In my app, I've functionality that user can register via mobile number using OTP. I haven't declare any sms related permission in my manifest still it is working when I run through android studio, but when I tried with uploaded APK in play store, but I'm not getting any SMS.

How?

Or I can add SEND_SMS or RECEIVE_SMS permission, but it'll be rejected by Google because they consider that this permission are sensitive, and I also searched about that, but don't know how to solve it.

Link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tekitsolution.remindly

Comment: For registering via OTP you don't need any special Permissions since you are not sending or reading messages from User's device. Can you give some more detail about what are you exactly doing the question needs more detail.

Comment: @Hamza when user will enter number, I sent to server and then from server side it'll send the code into user's device.

Comment: So are you not receiving OTP from server after sending number to server?

Comment: @Hamza yup when I test play store apk

Comment: Have you checked the server side? Are you receiving the number on server side when you check from playstore apk?

Comment: yes, I'm receiving

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any permission for SMS unless you are reading or sending messages from User's device. This issue is related to server side.

There are a few things you should check to get it resolved.

- Check if you are receiving the number on server side.
- Any library being used on server side to send messages isn't being taken as spam or is working fine
- The Release URL's are correct.

Hope this helps. Happy Codding!

Comment: There is nothing issue from server side. I told you that even right now if I install app from AS, I'll get OTP instantly, but when I download app from play store and install, I won't get OTP

Comment: Have you checked it on different devices?